# Writing atoi function via assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

For my exam I have to write atoi function that converts string into integer using assembly language. This what I've ended up with. The idea was to take string of numbers substract '0' and get integer.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int iOut = 0;
        char pcInp[4] = {'1' , '2' , '3' , '4'};
    __asm {
                        push eax
                        push ebx
                        push ecx
                        push edx
                        mov eax, pcInp
                        sub eax, '0'
                        mov iOut, eax
                        pop edx
                        pop ecx
                        pop ebx
                        pop eax
        }
        cout << "The number was processed as: " << iOut << endl;
```

The problem is when i input for example 123 it outputs random different numbers. I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I have never worked with assembly and my teacher just gave me this task. Could you please help me figure out what's worng? Or maybe my whole concept is wrong?

Comment: `123` is three characters, so `pcInp1` will contain the value `'1'`. Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: @NeilKirk umm.. no, I expect it to take all 3 of them.

Comment: @Martin How do you expect to input 3 characters into a type (`char`) that can only hold one character?  You should skip inputting numbers and instead declare a char array and fill it in with hard-coded values.  The title of your post has nothing to do with inputting correctly.

Comment: Hint: you need to *loop.*

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my bad there completely stupid mistake.. now I've changed that to hardcoded array of char, but I get an error in this line "mov eax, pcInp". It says operand size conflict..

Comment: You could write the code in C++ (avoiding function calls) and check the disassembly output of your compiler.

Comment: You need a loop in your code, and somewhere, you'll need to multiply the current number by ten, and you will need to calculate the index into the array [or create separate variable that is a pointer, and update that for each iteration]. I would start by writing the code in C or C++, and then convert it to assembler, rather than writing assembler first. That way, you know what you are meant to do, even if you don't know how to express it in assembler. [No point in pushing/popping registers you are not using either]

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think you are right. Ill try to do that in C++ first. Thanks for advice.

Comment: You want `movzbl eax,pcInp1`.  That's the unsigned version, which should be good enough here